# Can Chilopoda "vocalize" or produce sound for the express purpose of communication, as opposed to sound as a byproduct of other movements?

Tags: zoology, physiology, ethology, hearing, arthropod

Is there any species of Chilopoda that can "vocalize" or or otherwise produce sound for the express purpose of communication, as opposed to sounds it might create  as a byproduct of other movements and body functions?

An example of non-communication sound in other arthropods would be insects wings causing "buzz" sounds while in flight.

An example of a communication sound in other arthropods would be crickets (and others) rubbing their legs together to "chirp".

Do any Chilopoda intentionally create sound for the purpose of communication?

Comment: We are starting a Bioacoustics Stack Exchange for people interested in the studies of non-human animal sounds and the impacts of sounds on animals. Please join us! https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126698/bioacoustics?referrer=YjZmYjUxYzJkNDI1YmY5NDk3NzdhMzViMmZlNzI4ZDdiYTAyMWQxNTM5ZWFiNzRhODNkMmFiMzIxZjI3MmY1N_gFvrICTvBsmYNJ2ptRM6lIZEAV-VGkXtIwNyVDja680

Comment: @ASimonis Can you please stop to write your comment under each seamingly fitting question? In this frequency this can be seen as spam. Most of these questions (if not all) are old anyways and your comment will be useless.

Comment: I have been trying to help the Bioacoustics community grow and thrive, and I am sorry if the comments were inappropriate. I recently learned about the Chat space, so I'll try to direct some recruitment effort over there.  :-)

Comment: @ASimonis Unfortunately I cannot, in good conscience, indicate that I will commit to use that new Bioacoustics Stack Exchange, as I don't believe I would use it for anything other than attempting to get a single answer to this same question I've posted here.  My interest in bioacoustics is limited to this one specific use case.  If the stack exchange does gain enough support to be fully created, I will likely repost this question there, but that will likely be the full extend of my use of it.